# Pass data from one View Controller to another when button is pressed

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield, nsviewcontroller

This is a macOSX Cocoa Swift question, not iOS.

I have two view controllers [ViewController] & [SecondView].

The [SecondView] has a button with a string value attached. I want to be able to push the button and have the string value populate in my NSTextField on my [ViewController].

Example: (SecondView)

```
@IBAction func repair(_ sender: Any) {
        solution.stringValue += "Repair needed"
```

BUTTON PRESSED - pass string to [ViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var solution: NSTextField!
```

Comment: @the4kman - You tagged me in a question that deals with iOS UI and not macOS Cocoa Swift.

Comment: This is similar if you're using storyboards.